# Write, save and update info in Android

Tags: android, database, file, store

I am looking for a noob-friendly tutorial about how to write, save and update certain info from a file, also, would you recommend me to use a file or is it better to use a tinny database? (Its my first Android project ever, so yeah, the simpler, the better).

What I need to do is basically save the name of 2 players and their current won matches and be able to show that info in an Activity plus acumulating new wins and deleting their scores.

Comment: Better to go with Database.

Comment: How about doing Google and trying out first?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @PareshMayani How about I've already tried but I'm looking to contrast the ideas and help that people from stackoverflow can give me? Thanks for beeing rude, welcome to the internet.

Comment: @user3272243 Nope I am not rude but as you are asking about tutorials directly so I said to try out first. BTW, thanks for the warm welcome on Internet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer the database option and I believe that's what you should do. There are a lot of good tutorials. Try googling for SQLite. SQLite is very easy to use

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Here is a nice tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I don't know if it means anything but that tutorial is a bit old, maybe: http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I've already checked the developers link before posting this here but definetly the links that you and @newboyhun linked look quite nice and simple